# How can I get photos off my IPhone to my Macbook without using ICloud?

Tags: iphone, photos

I would like to transfer photos from my iPhone to my iCloud. I have a large volume of photos, many for work, which need to be backed up and removed from my phone. I would need to buy a higher tier of iCloud to put the photos into iCloud, and I have my own local backup.

It's fine for this to be a one time manual operation.

I have tried to use the photos app, but the import functionality doesn't show my iphone as it does in the tutorials, even with the phone connected by cable with trust enabled.

My iOS version is 14.7.1.

My OSX version is 10.13.6.

Comment: Have you tried using the Image Capture app on your Mac? If my iPhone is plugged into the Mac, then it shows as a device.

Comment: Works! Go ahead and put that as an answer @benwiggy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your iPhone is connected directly to your Mac, then it will appear as a Device in Image Capture, from where you can select Photos and import them.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple correct answers.  You just need to choose one that suits your workflow.

I use [PhotoSync](https://www.photosync-app.com/home.html).  It is an iOS app with a Mac companion app.  With the companion app running all the time on my Mac, I can initiate uploads (and downloads) from my iPhone.   This requires the iPhone and Mac on the same LAN - it doesn't use any cloud service.

Answer (score 1):

If your iPhone and Mac both have Bluetooth enabled, and both are connected to the same wifi network, photos can be moved from one to the other using AirDrop, part of the macOS/iOS functionality. Read more [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204144).

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox app (and Google Photos, probably others) provides the functionality to get the photos to your Mac if you're looking to do this without plugging the iOS device into your Mac.